# Count generic DIV tags with no name or ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I use javascript to count the number of DIV tags? The only properties WILL always be the `style="font-family:Courier New;"`

```
<div style="font-family:Courier New;">Some text</div>
<div style="font-family:Courier New;">Some text</div>
<div style="font-family:Courier New;">Some text</div>
```

There are other DIV's in the page. I'm only trying to target the ones that have `style="font-family:Courier New;"`
Any help?

Comment: O without jQuery: `document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;`

Comment: This counts ALL DIVs in the page. Im trying to target the ones only with style="font-family:Courier New;"

Comment: Try using XPath, it enables you to match tags based on attributes :)
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_examples.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `querySelectorAll()`

```js
var courier = document.querySelectorAll('div[style="font-family:Courier New;"]');

for (var i = 0, len = courier.length; i < len; i++) {
 courier[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<div style="font-family:Courier New;">Some text</div>
<div style="font-family:Courier New;">Some text</div>
<div style="font-family:Arial;">Some text</div>
<div style="font-family:Courier New;">Some text</div>
```

Now, you can write a query exactly as you would in CSS.

Works in all major browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: Should selector string be `div[style="font-family:Courier New;"]` ?

Comment: You could add a `*` before the `=`: `document.querySelectorAll('div[style*="font-family:Courier New;"]');` this will allow elements like this: `<div style="color:red;font-family:Courier New;">Some text</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery:

```
console.log($("[style='font-family:Courier New;']").length);
```